# PHP compare asian character with similar_text

Tags: php, similarity

I am using similar_text to compare and categorize item in to category, it works magically beside a few products.

provided categories `紹菜` (cabbage) and `長紹菜` (long cabbage)

and product name `新順園 紹菜` (some brand name, cabbage)

```
similar_text('新順園 紹菜', '長紹菜', $test1);  //56% 
similar_text('新順園 紹菜', '紹菜', $test2);  //54.54%
```

the answer should be the opposite where 新順園 紹菜 belong in the 紹菜 category.

I believe `similar_text()` take character count in consideration since  `長紹菜` are similar to `新順園 紹菜` in term of character count.

I can't use regex since items are not organize in the same way.  how would i do about this?